# Trying to reuse a timer for cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer, nstimer

So my goal is to re-use a timer for every cell. Every thing is working fine except one fine point. The cell.indexpath.row start at 1 instead of 0. And even when I scroll to the top, and it bounces back, it goes to 1. The problem with this is that the timer is created based on the IndexPath. I've tried quite a few workarounds of increasing the size of the cell, uncesfully trying the begin and end updates route but can't seem to lock this in. Any suggestions based upon the code I already have, or a new solution to the problem?

TimerVC

```
     var timer = Timer()
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return LiveActivityArray.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "liveCell", for: indexPath) as? liveActivitiesCell {
            //print("VISBLE CELL \(tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows)")
            // var visibleCells = self.tableview.visibleCells
var prop = hudProp()
                    Prop = LiveActivityArray[indexPath.item]
            cell.configureCell(properties: Prop, timer: &timer)
                    cell.property = Prop
                    cell.delegateFavorite = self
                    cell.delegate = self
                    cell.indexpath = indexPath
                    print("INDEX PATH CELL \(cell.indexpath.row)")

                    cell.StartTimerFilter(timer: &timer)

                    return cell
    }
    }
      return UITableViewCell()

}
```

TableviewCell

```
func configureCell(properties: hudProp, timer: inout Timer) {

  if DataService.instance.BothDatesReturnedTrue == true {
        timer.invalidate()
    StartTimerFilter(timer: &timer)
    }


@objc func TimerFuncFilter(timer: Timer) {

     property.getAuctionTime(property.Begin, AuctionEnd: property.End, postAuctionStart: _leftLabel: leftTime, _leftLabelDayHour: leftTimeDaysHrs, _midLabel: midTime, _midLabelHourMin: midTimeHrsMin, _rightLabel: rightTime, _rightLabelMinSec: rightTimeMinSec, _timer: timer, EndsLabelFunc: EndsOnLabel, EndsDateLabelFunc: EndsOnDateLabel)
    }
}
func StartTimerFilter(timer: inout Timer) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(liveActivitiesCell.TimerFuncFilter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     DataService.instance.BothDatesReturnedTrue = false
}
```

So as you can see I keep invalidating the timer for each new cell, but again the problem is that it starts on one. Can I continue to use this code and modify something or should I rethink the architecture of this problem.

Thank you in advance, I've tried solving this for weeks now with a lot of failed solutions.

Comment: have you tried using `Prop = LiveActivityArray[indexPath.row]` instead of `Prop = LiveActivityArray[indexPath.item]`?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing. I thought about that too.

Comment: set a breakpoint at the first line inside the `cellForRowAt` function, and step through it when indexPath.row is 0.

Comment: I'll try right now, but I think it starts at 1 always. I think all tabviews do that if I'm not correct

Comment: indexPath.row starts at 0.

Comment: No, no, I'm just saying if you go to a tableview and do the same think. The IndexPath.row for the cell will be one. Yes it starts at 0, if you scroll the right way, but it's not starting there.

Comment: Well I'm wrong. It starts at 0 with the breakpoint but keeps updating to 1. I'm just wondering have I'm going to use that or make it stop from going to 1. Any suggestions?

Comment: which line changes it to 1?

Comment: Just a tableview.reloaddata does. It just keeps looping through it and hits one

Comment: For one thing, you're replacing `timer` with a new Timer instance every time `StartTimerFilter` is called. I'm not sure what you're tying to do.

Comment: I'm creating a new timer for every cell. Is it possible to keep multiple timers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone is struggling or having a similar situation, the solution is to not have a timer in your view controller but keep it entirely in your view. The second aspect that made everything work with not running into retain cycle for to many timers was to use a

```
func prepareForReuse() {
super.prepareForReuse
 timer.invalidate
}
```